# Xamarin : Inheriting from AlertDialog class

Tags: inheritance, xamarin, android-alertdialog

I am trying to write a class that inherits from AlertDialog class but I am receiving a compilation error " 'Android.App.AlertDialog' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments "

Here is my code, plain and simple!

```
class AlertDialogExtender : AlertDialog
{

}
```

I tried to add an empty constructor to comply with the error message, but no luck

```
class AlertDialogExtender : AlertDialog
{
    public AlertDialogExtender()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explicitly need to invoke one of the existing constructors from the super class. The error tells you, that there is no zero-argument constructor in `Android.App.AlertDialog`. [This](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.App.AlertDialog%2fC) page lists available constructors.

The general way to invoke a super-constructor then goes like this:

```
class AlertDialogExtender : AlertDialog
{
    public AlertDialogExtender() : base(/* params for super constructor */) { }
}
```

The parameters passed to `base` can either be constants (such as `MyClass() : base("value")`) or parameters from the current class' constructor (such as `MyClass(string x) : base(x)`).

See [C# Reference: base](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) for more details.